# implementation and effect of periodic execution of application(timer driven) in python

Tags: python, timer, operating-system

I have two python application which are timer driven. These applications gets executed at every fixed interval of time. The code driven by timers are driven like this:

```
while True:  
 do_something()  
 sleep(10)
```

I have few questions:

1. The application needs to get executed periodically. Is the above stated way is correct ?
2. Does it really needed to **daemonize** these sort of applications or simply running in background with help of some tools like **upstart** will be OK ? How these two approaches are different ?
3. If we have more than one application on a single machine (consider multi core cpu ) then how does these applications are going to **get system resources during execution**?
4. What happen if cpu is busy executing other tasks and meanwhile timer expires for these applications, whetherthe job running on cpu will get preempted or will it depend on nature of job. So if the job is non-preemptive , my understanding goes that this job will get queued for processing. If this is the case , then how to make application to run at every definite time interval.

Comment: why not cron or scheduled task(on windows)? I think it's easier way to do periodic jobs than daemonize application.

Comment: @hago I assume u hv answered question number 2, so after all the daemon will have to execute code periodically. So what is the difference? ya i know cron is another way , but that was not the question 2. The question(2) is how **daemonizing the application and running the application in background with help of upstart or cron is different**.

Comment: daemonizing the application costs more time than cron for me, :-). Daemonizing it usually means adding many codes to the application and make it bigger and more complicated, and also means more time to debug and test it. That's why I don't prefer that way. However, a daemonized application can hold a continuous context and is capable of listening and serving request, if those are your need.

Answer (score 0):

[Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) is the industry standard for delayed and periodic tasks.

Benefits from using Celery is:

1. You can control and prevent tasks overlapping
2. Your tasks manage by your code not by OS
3. And many more for periodic tasks you can view [Celery pereodic task](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html)

Comment: Celery can't be the answer of my question. My req. is very simple , that I have two very simple python application which needed to be executed periodically and I don't want something like celery to do all this.

Comment: The **great person** who has just down voted this question, could have please enlightened me with his/her knowledge, by simply answering my question. Instead of answering or having discussion on the question, down voting the question doesn't make sense. I am ready for discussion , about the importance of this question.